# Webpack-2 externals how to load bootstrap from cdn

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cdn, webpack-2

I created my webpack config file and it works fine. I want to use externals to load some libs from CDN:

```
externals:{
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        moment: "moment",
        Highcharts:'highcharts',
        tether: 'tether',
        Tether: 'tether',
        'window.Tether': 'tether'
        }
```

Still I cannot load bootstrap. I tried `bootstrap:'bootstrap' bootstrap:true` but it doesn't work.
I tried `import` and `require` in my file.
When i require jquery `var $ = require('../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery');` bootstrap modal gets error, and when I comment out require `jquery` I see a `jquery` error.

For now I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into bootstrap source code, it exports an object with following items (refer to file `bootstrap/js/src/index.js`:

```
export {
  Util,
  Alert,
  Button,
  Carousel,
  ...
}
```

So, to add them as externals, the entry should be:

```
webpackConfig.externals = {
    jquery: '$',
    bootstrap: {
        Util: 'Util',
        Alert: 'Alert',
        Button: 'Button',
        Carousel: 'Carousel',
        Collapse: 'Collapse',
        Dropdown: 'Dropdown',
        Modal: 'Modal',
        Popover: 'Popover',
        Scrollspy: 'Scrollspy',
        Tab: 'Tab',
        Tooltip: 'Tooltip'
    },
    ...
}
```